# jQuery No Conflict Still Conflicts with Other Version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am trying to run the dual slider plugin alongside with an estalge view-box. They both use jQuery, and work separately but when i placed them together, one breaks. I have tried implementing the jQuery no conflict rule, but i think i may be missing a small detail somewhere. My coding so far looks like :

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.timers-1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.dualSlider.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- START ESTALGE -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.etalage.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                jQuery('#etalage').etalage();
            });

    $(".carousel").dualSlider({
                auto:true,
                autoDelay: 6000,
                easingCarousel: "swing",
                easingDetails: "easeOutBack",
                durationCarousel: 1000,
                durationDetails: 500

            });

    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: noConflict is meant to stop jQuery from interfering with other libraries, not from itself.  In other words, I think you're out of luck unless you're willing to use one version of jQuery and stick with it.

Comment: @Corbin: You can have multiple versions of jQuery, `$.noConflict` will return the `jQuery` function from the 2nd one.

Comment: @Corbin That is simply not true. noConflict can and will prevent jQuery from conflicting with another copy of itself.

Comment: @Corbin I thought the same thing five minutes ago, but I have since been corrected. Multiple versions are supported; however, plugin compatibility depends on the plugins being well-designed, using the classic `function($){}(jQuery)` IIFE formulation.

Comment: Then I stand very much corrected :).

Answer (score 7):

You are using `noConflict` incorrectly.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- INCLUDE ANY SCRIPTS HERE THAT RELY ON 1.3.2 -->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // HERE WE CAN USE 1.3.2

    // re-assign 1.3.2 to a new variable so we can use it later
    var $jq132 = $.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    // $ is now 1.6.2 and $jq132 is 1.3.2, both can be used.

</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest also using $.noConflict(true) to ensure that the global `jQuery` variable is also reverted, though it may not be mandatory.

Comment: @KevinB Laid out in this way it wouldn't matter actually.  If done the way @Rocket has it then you would have two different results based on whether or not you passed the true.  In my answer 1.6 will always claim `jQuery`.

Comment: This is the correct answer; the only possible problem with it would be that one of the 1.3.2 plugins isn't closing properly around the jQuery object, and tries to access the global $ object in its handlers. Unfortunately, especially for plugins that old, this is likelier than it should be. Still, @JamesMontagne is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple jQuery versions, [`$.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will return you the jQuery object.  You'd need to save it as another variable.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $jq = $.noConflict();
    // $jq is jQuery 1.6.2
    // $ is jQuery 1.3.2
</script>
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/uhazan/3/edit#javascript,html,live

NOTE: The `jQuery` variable will be set to 1.6.2 (the 2nd one), if you want it to be 1.3.2 (the 1st one), pass `true` to `$.noConflict`.

P.S. You may want to put your `$(".carousel").dualSlider` inside the `$(document).ready(`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this technique doesn't reliably work with plugins, which is why he's including an old version of jQuery in the first place. Plugins expect jQuery to be available at a certain global.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your `slider` inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`

From the owner [site](http://ftp.codecanyon.net/item/etalage/faq/180719)

**Does Etalage support jQuery no-conflict mode?**

The plugin itself is noconflict ready. Just replace the `"$"` with `"jQuery"` where you initiate the plugin, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#etalage').etalage();
});
```

Comment: As long as `jQuery` points to the correct version.  In the OP's example `jQuery` would be 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(".carousel").dualSlider({` line is outside the `jQuery(document).ready()` function, which I'm pretty sure is not your intention. For the moment, this would work:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#etalage').etalage();

    $(".carousel").dualSlider({
        auto:true,
        autoDelay: 6000,
        easingCarousel: "swing",
        easingDetails: "easeOutBack",
        durationCarousel: 1000,
        durationDetails: 500
    });
});
```

However, there are other problems with your code. You are bringing in two versions of jQuery, one of which is very old (1.3.2). You won't get good results with this. If there is some library that relies on older jQuery, please consider not using that library. It probably won't work well on this page anyway, since any runtime activity of that library will only have access to jQuery 1.6. The [jQuery .noConflict docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mention that you can supply boolean `true` as an argument to `.noConflict` in order to free up the jQuery keyword as well, but by that time, your loaded plugins have already closed around the old version.

Comment: Your final bold statement isn't entirely true.  It also enables you to use multiple versions of jquery.

Comment: You can, but it's not really designed for that. Plugins, especially, expect jQuery to be available, at the very least, via the jQuery global. If OP has modified the plugins to account for this, then that's great, but in general it's not a recommended usage because of the unexpected effects.

Comment: Any plugin that requires that `jQuery` be available at all times is a poorly written plugin.  A good plugin only needs it to exist at the time the plugin is loaded.

Comment: @zetlen: `$.noConflict` *is* designed to manage different jQuery versions.  Take a look at the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/  In the last example, it shows `// Do something with another version of jQuery`.  I'd say it was designed to do that.

Comment: A well written plugin is in this format:  `(function( $ ){})( jQuery );`  As long as `jQuery` exists initially, the plugin has a reference to it forever.

Comment: Would that all plugins were well-written. You guys are right, though; the jQuery docs do mention that multiple versions are supported through `.noConflict()`. I was wrong and I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two jQuery Core Lib includes

Try this instead:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.timers-1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.dualSlider.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- START ESTALGE -->
<script src="js/jquery.etalage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 jQuery('#etalage').etalage();
 jQuery(".carousel").dualSlider({
            auto:true,
            autoDelay: 6000,
            easingCarousel: "swing",
            easingDetails: "easeOutBack",
            durationCarousel: 1000,
            durationDetails: 500

        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't jquery.easing.js included in jquery-1.6.2.min.js?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use multiple versions of jquery then use

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Now call the older version of jquery like

```
jq132('element').doSomething();
```

and newer version of jquery could be as follows

```
$('element').doSomething();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this technique doesn't reliably work with plugins, which is why he's including an old version of jQuery in the first place. Plugins expect jQuery to be available at a certain global.