# Why does this Jquery content slider work in Chrome & Safari but not Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

Perplexed as to why my JQuery image slider won't work in Firefox. Works OK in Safari & Chrome, yet to test in IE. It's a basic click-a-button-and-the-next-image-slides-across, see it in action here:

http://www.alihaberfield.com/test/carouseltest/carouseltest.html

Here's the JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {


var theImage = $('.gallery_wrap ul li img');
var theWidth = 790;  
//wrap into mother div
$('.gallery_wrap ul').wrap('<div id="mother" />');                  
//assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
$('#mother').css({
    width: 790,
    height: 780,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden'      
});
    //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 
var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
$('.gallery_wrap ul').css({
    width: function(){
    return totalWidth;  
}               
});     
$(theImage).each(       
    function(intIndex){             
            $(this).nextAll('a')
            .bind("click", function(){
                if($(this).is(".next")) {

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * theWidth)             
                    }, 1000)                    

                } else if($(this).is(".previous")){

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * theWidth)             
                    }, 1000)    


                } else if($(this).is(".startover")){

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (0)              
                    }, 1000)

                }
            });//close .bind()                                   
});//close .each()                      
});//doc ready
```

It's based on this simple jquery slider, which I will note DOES work in Firefox:

http://brenelz.com/blog/build-a-content-slider-with-jquery/

The major differences between that slider and mine are that:

1. I'm using an older JQuery library- required by the client due to legacy blah etc. I'm using 1.3.2.
2. I have added a .gallery_wrap selector to the ul rules in JQuery, so that the JQuery doesn't wrap every list on the page with a mother div.
3. Since I know the sizes of the images, I made the size of var theWidth static at 790px, which fixed an issue with this gallery not showing up inside of a lightbox (without a static width, none of the size calculations worked on content that was set to display:none).

Hypothesis 1: That the negative margin behaviour is not triggering in Firefox due to the older JQuery version.
Hypothesis 2: That adding a static width has messed with Firefox's calculation of the negative margins.

Any better hypotheses, info about other browsers it doesn't work on/other ways it fails, or suggestions for how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: check the console it return the following error
**The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.**

Comment: head tag also not closed properly

Comment: Thanks, the head tag slip is embarrassing, but I don't think either of those were causing the problem. Fix below.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer: script was not working properly with older version of JQuery.

Would not work in Firefox (or IE, as it happened) using Jquery 1.3. Worked perfectly in all browsers with JQuery 1.4 and above.

Problem solved by loading two libraries and using the JQuery noconflict structure provided in the excellent answer on this page:

[jQuery No Conflict Still Conflicts with Other Version of jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131268/jquery-no-conflict-still-conflicts-with-other-version-of-jquery)